# How to search for a matching pattern only in the first line across multiple files?

Tags: search, multiple-files

How do I search in multiple files for 1st line of file matching a pattern?

e.g. I want to search for files starting with `++`

```
++ Heading 1
```

and not

```
+ Heading 1

++ Heading 2
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: "files", "lines", something else? Please fix your question.

Comment: Sorry, first line of file. Fixed question.

Comment: Both answers given by kenorb & PhillipFrank worked, I was able to use argdo to find and substitute all occurrences, and vimgrep to check which files have been changed. I've marked one to close this question, but both solutions work. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `:vimgrep` as below:

```
:vimgrep /\%(\%<2l\)foo/ *.*
```

This will search for `foo` in all files in the current folders (`*.*`) only in the 1st line (`<2l`).

Alternatively may search either in the current file (`%`), certain files (`*.c`) or recursively (`**/*.*`, see: `:help starstar-wildcard`). See: `:help :vimgrep` and `:help /\%>l`.

To jump between patterns, use `:cn[ext]` and `:cp[revious]`. See more at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7880372/55075).

However there is no straight forward solution to use [substitution on quickfix list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5686206/55075).

---

To search and replace pattern for the first line only for multiple-files, you can use Ex command:

```
$ ex +'bufdo!1s/php/bar/ge' -cxa *.*
```

<sup>Note: The `:bufdo` command is not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For doing something to multiple files, `:argdo` is your friend. You might need to edit the argument list first. It's set to the opened files on vim start, you can output it with `:args` and set it with, e.g., `:args *.txt`. After that, a simple `:argdo /^++` will search for the first line that starts with `++` and puts the cursor there.

That assumes the cursor is on the first line of each buffer. To assure that, use `:argdo :normal 1G` first.

Note that you did not specify to do anything special with that line, so I've just performed the search here (search as in "put the cursor there").

---

Edit: If you wanto to substitute something, just use the usual vim command for argdo, i.e. `:argdo %s/^++/--/ge`. Note that for edits you should use `:set hidden`, otherwise it won't be able to switch buffers. Use the `e` qualifier for the substitution so the command doesn't stop at a buffer with no match.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify that I'd like to search in 1st line of files matching a pattern, and replace it with something else. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've augmented my answer, is that what you wanted?

Comment: I believe @ayutheos wants to find `^++` only when it appears in the first line in the file, not find the first occurrence of a line that matches `^++`.

Comment: I think therefore that `:argdo 1s/^++/--/e` should suffice.

Comment: @Rich Yes, that's what I wanted, thanks for clarifying :) . I found that both solutions given by kenorb and PhillipFrank worked (vimgrep gives a quicklist, while argdo substitutes all files in arglist). Thank you!